# Progress bar animation to lazy loading listview

Tags: android, lazy-loading

I am using lazy loading in my app, I want to show the loading animation or progress bar or anything till the content loads from remote server just to tell the user that the page is not blank or under construction. Here is my activity, plz tell me the solution to make user wait till content loads.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hotel_listview);

    // URL to the XML data
    String strUrl = "http://xxx.php";

    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download xml data
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

    // Starting the download process
    downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
    if (!isOnline(this)) {
        showDialog(DIALOG_ERROR_CONNECTION); //displaying the created dialog.
    } else {
        //Internet available. Do what's required when internet is available.
    }



}
public boolean isOnline(Context c) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) c
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (ni != null && ni.isConnected())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog = null;
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_ERROR_CONNECTION:
            AlertDialog.Builder errorDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            errorDialog.setTitle("Error");
            errorDialog.setMessage("Connection Error....!");
            errorDialog.setNeutralButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog errorAlert = errorDialog.create();
            return errorAlert;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return dialog;
}
/** A method to download xml data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
        iStream.close();
    }
    return data;
}

/** AsyncTask to download xml data */
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    String data = null;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try{
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result != null) {
        // The parsing of xml data is done in a non-ui thread
        ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();

        // Start parsing xml data
        listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);
    }}
}

/** AsyncTask to parse xml data and load ListView */
private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter>{

    StringReader reader;

    // Doing the parsing of xml data in a non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strXml) {
        try{
            reader = new StringReader(strXml[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("XML Exception1",e.toString());
        }

        // Instantiating xml parser class
        HotelListParser hotelListParser = new HotelListParser();

        // A list object to store the parsed countries list
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> hotelList = null;

        try{
            // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
            hotelList = hotelListParser.parse(reader);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "hotel","photo","rupees","review","distance"};

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.tv_hotelName,R.id.iv_photo,R.id.tv_rupees,R.id.tv_review,R.id.tv_distance};

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), hotelList, R.layout.hotel_listview_layout, from, to);

        return adapter;
    }

    /** Invoked by the Android when "doInBackground" is executed */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {
        // Setting adapter for the listview
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
            String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("photo_path");
            ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();

            HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            hm.put("photo_path",imgUrl);
            hm.put("position", i);

            // Starting ImageLoaderTask to download and populate image in the listview
            imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);
        }


    }
}

/** AsyncTask to download and load an image in ListView */
private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{

    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

        InputStream iStream=null;
        String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("photo_path");
        int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(imgUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            // Getting Caching directory
            File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

            // Temporary file to store the downloaded image
            File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+position+".png");

            // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
            FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

            // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);

            // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);

            // Flush the FileOutputStream
            fOutStream.flush();

            //Close the FileOutputStream
            fOutStream.close();

            // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position in the listview
            HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            // Storing the path to the temporary image file
            hmBitmap.put("photo",tmpFile.getPath());

            // Storing the position of the image in the listview
            hmBitmap.put("position",position);

            // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and position
            return hmBitmap;

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
        if (result != null) {
            // Getting the path to the downloaded image
            String path = (String) result.get("photo");

        // Getting the position of the downloaded image
        int position = (Integer) result.get("position");

        // Getting adapter of the listview
        SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter ) mListView.getAdapter();

        // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the listview
        HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);

        // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter
        hm.put("photo",path);

        // Noticing listview about the dataset changes
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }}
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

Progress Dialog method to show and hide. **Or** you can write code in onPreExecute() to show and onPostExecute() to hide the progress dialog.

```
    ProgressDialog barProgressDialog;

    public void showHideProgressDialog(boolean status){
           if(barProgressDialog==null){
              barProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
              barProgressDialog.setTitle("Title");
              barProgressDialog.setMessage("Your Message");
           }

      if(status){
         barProgressDialog.show();
      }else{
         barProgressDialog.dismiss();
      }
    }
```

AsyncTask methods.

```
public void onPreExecute(...){
  showHideProgressDialog(true)
  ..
}

public void onPostExecute(...){
  showHideProgressDialog(false)
  ...
}
```

**Suggestion** : Do http stuff only when device has a data connection

```
.....

     DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

    // dont call http stuff here   
    //downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
    if (!isOnline(this)) {
        showDialog(DIALOG_ERROR_CONNECTION); //displaying the created dialog.
    } else {
        //Internet available. Do what's required when internet is available.
        downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
    }
....
```

Comment: my activity doesnt have the pre execute thing, will you plz tell me what should I write in preExecute,

Comment: I tried adding your code in postExecute but it continues showing dialogue even after loading is completed